# toolkit:ListPicker is Null when trying to set ItemSource

Tags: c#, .net, windows-phone-8, toolkit, wptoolkit

Quite new to Windows Phone Applications.

Trying to create something similar to a Drop Down List, found the ListPicker.
After doing some more research once it didn't work, I have come to the following code:

```
<toolkit:ListPicker x:Name="listActions" Grid.Row="1" Width="340" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Center">
            <toolkit:ListPicker.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <StackPanel>
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" />
                    </StackPanel>
                </DataTemplate>
            </toolkit:ListPicker.ItemTemplate>
            <toolkit:ListPicker.FullModeItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <StackPanel>
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" />
                    </StackPanel>
                </DataTemplate>
            </toolkit:ListPicker.FullModeItemTemplate>
        </toolkit:ListPicker>
```

However, when I try to set the ItemSource I am getting a Null Reference exception, which is coming from the ListPicker object.

```
listActions.ItemsSource = Storage.Register.ActionDefinitions;
```

Any ideas on why this is happening or how to fix it would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Are you sure listActions is null not the Storage.Register ?

Comment: The storage.Register had 2 items in it. was checking that. it definitely said that listActions was null. But its started working now because windows developing. thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure what happened. But I did all the usual things including wiping the code and re-making it identically. so weather something behind the code was missing or something I don't know. But it has started working now.

Thanks for the help, all information, weather useful or not so much is still greatly appreciated.

Comment: This may have been caused by the application on the emulator not updating when I try to run it. and having to close the emulator completely for any changes to work

Answer (score 0):

You haven't shown enough code to confirm it but the only reason this should happen would be if you were trying to set the `ItemsSource` in the page constructor before `InitializeComponent()` is called.

Comment: I am setting the ItemsSource in the PhoneApplicationPage_Loaded() method which, correct me if I am wrong, gets called after.